# Wrong output produced

Tags: c, data-structures

i'm trying to compile this for my class for tomorrow, do you have any idea why this code right here :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int row;
    int col;
    int value;
} term;

void smTranspose(term a[], term b[]) {
    int m, n, v, i, j, p;
    m = a[0].row;
    n = a[0].col;
    v = a[0].value;
    b[0].row = n;
    b[0].col = m;
    b[0].value = v;
    if (v > 0) {
        p = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= v; j++)
                if (a[j].col == i) {
                    b[p].row = a[j].col;
                    b[p].col = b[j].row;
                    b[p].value = a[j].value;
                    printf("<%d %d %d>\n", b[p].row, b[p].col, b[p].value);
                    p++;
                }
    }
}
int main() {
    term a[3] = { { 1,1,8 },{ 2,1,9 },{ 1,3,17 } };
    term b[3];

    smTranspose(a, b);

    getchar();

}
```

produces wrong output like this ?

```
<0 1 0>
<0 0 1688502961>
```

It's a program that tries to create a transpose of a matrix, with parameters a and b, a being the inputted matrix. As you can see right here, the output will display the transposed matrix's row, column, and value. Please help!

I am new on this forum so please let me know if my post violate any laws and stuff. Thank you!

Comment: And what is the *expected* output? Have you tried stepping though the code line by line in  a debugger to see what happens?

Comment: As a new user, it is _your_ responsibility to get to know the rules before posting. Read [ask]. Then read the [faq]. And bear in mind that you are expected to do your homework first, which includes _debugging_ your code and describing the results of your debugging attemps. The way it is right now, your question is a debug-this-for-me request and those are not well received here.

Comment: By the way, when you do `b[p].col = b[j].row;` then `b[j]` might be uninitialized I think. Do you mean to use `a[j].row`?

Comment: also `for (j = 1; j <= v; j++)
                if (a[j].col == i) {` occurs out of bounds.

Comment: How about adding some meaning variable names? Like, instead of `a` and `b`, you could use `inputTerms` and `resultTerms`. Cryptic one-character variable names might be all the rage for 1337 d00dz, but real programmers make their code easily understandable.

Answer (score -1):

Just a little suggestion here, a matrix can be represented directly by a flat array, that way you'd simplify your code quite a lot, ie:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void transpose(int *a, int *b) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            b[y * 3 + x] = a[x * 3 + y];
        }
    }
}

void print_matrix(int *m) {
    printf("\n");
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            printf("%d ", m[y * 3 + x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {1, 1, 8, 2, 1, 9, 1, 3, 17};
    int b[9];

    transpose(a, b);
    print_matrix(a);
    printf("----------");
    print_matrix(b);
}
```

With fixed size of 3x3 you don't need check boundaries.

As for your homework, I'll leave to make the whole debugging to you ;)